# How to search by place name in google places API? Android

Tags: android, google-places-api

so let's say the user is trying to find Mcdonalds for example, is there a way to allow the user to search for the restaurant/hotel etc... by its name? so when the user types Mcdonalds it shows the nearest one or anything similar?

Comment: What you are looking for is here: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests. You need to pass in the `keyword` field and it's value as `McDonalds`.

Comment: oh!, I did not find this page before, thank you so much!